# Fix y-values in Jupyter matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I wrote some simple code for a graph for a Jupyter notebook kernel (working in VS, downloaded Jupyter as an extension). The code works fine, but it *kinda* simplified the y-values, or they might be wrong entirely.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s=1) # s is the size of the point, 2 and 4 are coordinates

# Set chart title and label axes.
ax.set_title("Square numbers", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize=14)

# Set size of tick labels.
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# Set the range for each axis.
ax.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])

plt.show()
```

Here's a photo of what the graph looks like (I don't know why it's so big, sorry about that):

[image: weird graph]

So essentially, why does the graph show y-values that aren't something among the lines of `200000`, `400000`, etc? Also, what does `le6` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that Matplotlib is using [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) (E notation) when formatting the axis, it is simply a multiplier for the numbers show, `1e6` means `1 x 10⁶`. For example, `0.2 x 1e6` would be `0.2 x 1 x 10⁶` which is 200000.

You can prevent this by making use of the `style` argument of [matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html):

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = range(1, 1001)
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s=1) # s is the size of the point, 2 and 4 are coordinates

# Set chart title and label axes.
ax.set_title("Square numbers", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize=14)

# Set size of tick labels.
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# Set the range for each axis.
ax.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.show()
```

[image]